# Smooth-out transition between css animations

Tags: css, animation, rotation

Is it possible to prevent the small 'lag' at the end of a css animation?

I am trying to have 4 balls spin around each other constantly. They spin fine, but at the end of each 360deg cycle, there is a very short but noticeable pause.
I know 'animation-fill-mode: forwards' is supposed to make the animation remember its' final state but that doesn't seem to fix the issue.

Perhaps there is a better way to set-up the rotation than the method I have used? Which makes the transition between each animation iteration smoother...

```
@keyframes container-rotate {
to {transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

animation-name: container-rotate;
animation-duration: 3s;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-timing-function: ease-in;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
```

Example here:
http://codepen.io/Recidvst/pen/wGbjvz

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the value of your `animation-timing-function` to `linear`. You're currently using `ease-in` and `ease-out` which vary the speed of the animation at the beginning or end. `linear` will use the same speed the whole time.

Updated [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xVvXNV).

[Here's some info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/timing-function) on what the various timing functions look like on a graph across time.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks very much, this is exactly what I needed. Appreciate the effort behind your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried animation-timing-function: linear;? or just leaving it as the default ease?